# Pattern match using Regex with substring limit

Tags: ios, swift, regex

I am working on pattern matching within a string messages for `*` character. So that I could identified any substring between two `*` characters.

I am able to do this using below regex

`[*]((?s).*?)[*]`

This regex return me all expected results, which I wanted except it also consider `*` pair, if two `*` characters are together like (ex:  `Test**ing`).

I need to avoid this case while matching pattern.

Is their any way, I can add some condition while regex match that if `*` character is followed by another *, then ignore that match and return match only if two `*` characters have another character/characters between them.

**For example:**

`**test`  -> This should not return any match

`***test*` -> It should return *test*

`***testing* message *additional*` ->  It should return *testing* and *additional*

Let me know, If something is unclear.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. You want to match the string `*test*`?

Comment: Your pattern should match with this regex. 
`[*]+([^*]+)?[*]+`

Comment: @fphilipe Yes, I wanted to match pattern, if string contains value within * characters like you said `*test*`.

Comment: Did you manage to get what you need? Does `(?s)[*](?![*])(.*?)(?<![*])[*]` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/XBpQEC/1)) solve the issue?  Are you extracting or replacing the matches? Please show the code.

Comment: No, I could not fix this using regex. So I continued with another way.

Answer (score -1):

`s` isn't the way to get a string in regex. We use `[a-z]`. To cater to all upper and lower cases between asterisks, use:

`[*](([A-Za-z]+).*?)[*]`

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/40CIJj/2) for the results this yields.